# Is multitenancy supported in wso2 identity server v5.11 github releases or do I need a subscription for the same?

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to utilise multitenancy feature in WSO2 by using github releases(https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0). I just wanted to understand if there are any limitations for the same between enterprise version downloaded from wso2 site and github releases.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @YCR answer, yes, multi tenancy is supported in IS 5.11.0 and IS 6.0.0 and it was supported throughout IS 5.x series. Please see [Tenant Management](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/tenants/tenant-mgt/) on WSO2 documentation.

Answer (score 4):

WSO2 doesn't have an Enterprise Version of the product. Everybody uses the same base release and if you have a subscription you will be receiving product updates for bug fixes, improvements, security issues etc. Other than that there are no hidden features or limitations in the Opensource version.(Rarely some features are introduced as updates, in these cases you may not receive them) The subscription is for getting updates and getting support from WSO2.

You can read more about WSO2 subscription from [here](https://wso2.com/subscription/).